# Wrap R function in python

Tags: python, r, ipython, rpy2

I would like to wrap a R function contained in a package princurve.
With ipython I do it successfully with an ipython cell R magic:

```
%%R -i X -o s,lambda
fit1<-principal.curve(X)
s <- fit1$s
l <- fit1$lambda
```

but I want a function that I can import from a module like:

```
from mymodule import principal_curve
s, l = principal_curve(X)
```

I guess I have to use rpy directly, I am not sure how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use R but using this example in the [docs](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/robjects_rpackages.html#importing-arbitrary-r-code-as-a-package) you can define a function and import it into a python module:

*r_mod.py*

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage

string = """
square <- function(x) {
    return(x^2)
}

cube <- function(x) {
    return(x^3)
}
"""

powerpack = SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage(string, "powerpack")
```

*py_mod.py*

```
from r_mod import powerpack

print powerpack.square(3)
[1] 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a function is in an R package, you can use `importr`:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
princurve = importr('princurve')

princurve.principal_curve(X)
```