# Is it possible to do Android development using the R programming language?

Tags: android, python, r

I'm doing digital signal processing work in R using R Studio and think it would be a neat idea to expand this into an Android app. I know people have used [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) to develop Android Apps in Python and I know it's possible to [wrap R code in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217997/wrap-r-function-in-python), so is this feasible? I read that it's possible to [run R code on Android](https://selbydavid.com/2017/12/29/r-android/), just not sure if adding it to my project is a possibility. I also don't need to have the entire app to be written in R. Are there any examples/documentation related to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36968411/3358272

Comment: Just because I've never *heard* of a deployed app running R does not mean there are none ... but I haven't. Give it a try! I might buy it.

Comment: I'll give it a try and post a response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you can! I've built a more complex app using [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) and the [rpy2 package](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/robjects_rpackages.html), but I'll demonstrate a simple example here.

You can define your R code like so:
*r_code.py*

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage

r_code = """
add <- function(x, y) {
    return(x + y)
}
"""

r_lib = SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage(r_code, "r_lib")
```

Your Kivy App will look something like this:
*main.py*

```
from kivy.app import App
from r_code import r_lib

class MainApp(App):
def build(self):
    window = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    label = Label(text=str(r_lib.add(3, 4)[0]))
    b.add_widget(label)
    return b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

And if you want to package this into an Android App, you can follow the directions from the [official doc](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html). If you run into an error with rpy2, you might have to install the correct version for your system from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2).

Happy coding!